# PHP get seeders/leechers of .torrent file

Tags: php, bittorrent

I need an easy to use torrent tracker that I can input the torrent file, and the PHP library will send me back seeders and leechers of the torrent file?

Comment: Do you understand what "tracker" means in the context of BitTorrent?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a tracker to get this information, there are a couple out there now XBTT was the most popular for years, now a private site has written their own in house tracker known as ocelot.  XBTT responds to a torrent clients http requests and stores information about that torrent in a database.  If you are interested in writing your own tracker the point to start is by inspecting the packets that a tracker sends and receives.

All torrent communication is handled via a RESTful GET request so packet inspection is easy.